# React Native Push Notifications with react-native-fcm

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

[I'm using this library.](https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm)

I'm attempting to get push notifications to display in the notifications tray on my Nexus 5 (android 6.0.1). Using React Native 0.42, React Native CLI 2.0.1. I'm developing on Ubuntu 14.04.

I'm using firebase. I go into my console > notifications > send a message > specific device (which I get from remote debugging console.log, below).

I am logging notifications, as you can see in code, and they do get to my device, as I can see them in the logs.

But, I don't know how to display them in the notifications tray. Looking through the docs and searching forums, it seems they should show up by default.

```
componentDidMount() {
        FCM.requestPermissions(); // for iOS
        FCM.getFCMToken().then(token => {
            console.log(token)
            // store fcm token in your server
        });
        this.notificationListener = FCM.on(FCMEvent.Notification, async (notif) => {
          console.log(notif)

        });
});
```

Comment: I am having same issue... Did you got any solution to this??

Comment: You must use the FCM.presentLocalNotification(). Because if your app is active the notification handling is on you whereas if it is inactive that is the phone that displays it auto

Answer (score 0):

It seems that "custom_notification" is required to display the notification in the top tray. I added this to my payload:

"custom_notification": {
      "body": "test body",
      "title": "test title",
      "color":"#00ACD4",
      "priority":"high",
      "icon":"ic_notif",
      "group": "GROUP",
      "id": "id",
      "show_in_foreground": true
    }

So, I think the app must receive the notification, parse out the data, and add this custom_notification parameter.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following in your constructor:

```
FCM.requestPermissions(); // for iOS
FCM.getFCMToken().then(token => {
  console.log(token)
  // store fcm token in your server
});

this.notificationListener = FCM.on(FCMEvent.Notification, async (notif) => {
  // do some component related stuff
  console.log(notif);
  //alert(notif.fcm.body);

  FCM.presentLocalNotification({
    id: "UNIQ_ID_STRING",                               // (optional for instant notification)
    title: "My Notification Title",                     // as FCM payload
    body: notif.fcm.body,                    // as FCM payload (required)
    sound: "default",                                   // as FCM payload
    priority: "high",                                   // as FCM payload
    click_action: "ACTION",                             // as FCM payload
    badge: 10,                                          // as FCM payload IOS only, set 0 to clear badges
    number: 10,                                         // Android only
    ticker: "My Notification Ticker",                   // Android only
    auto_cancel: true,                                  // Android only (default true)
    large_icon: "ic_launcher",                           // Android only
    icon: "ic_launcher",                                // as FCM payload, you can relace this with custom icon you put in mipmap
    big_text: "Show when notification is expanded",     // Android only
    sub_text: "This is a subText",                      // Android only
    color: "red",                                       // Android only
    vibrate: 300,                                       // Android only default: 300, no vibration if you pass null
    tag: 'some_tag',                                    // Android only
    group: "group",                                     // Android only
    picture: "https://google.png",                      // Android only bigPicture style
    ongoing: true,                                      // Android only
    my_custom_data: 'my_custom_field_value',             // extra data you want to throw
    lights: true,                                       // Android only, LED blinking (default false)
    show_in_foreground: true                                  // notification when app is in foreground (local & remote)
  });
});

FCM.subscribeToTopic('test_topic');
```